# Is there a way to apply a function to each parameter of another function/method in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, arguments, mapping

Let us suppose a following code where a method of an object accepts multiple integer parameters :

```
def my_function(target):
    return target + 2



my_object.DoSomething(param1=my_function(1), param2=my_function(4), param3=my_function(7))
```

Is there a way to map a single function to all parameters of a method like that?
If not, how would you approach it from efficiency standpoint if there were undefined number of parameters?

Please note I am aware of how Python's map() and Pandas' apply() work. Also the numbers above are just examples to illustrate my point.

Comment: You _could_ use a dictionary comprehension and just double-star it in the function call. Alternatively, if the parameters need not be named, you can always just unpack a single map object in the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your parameters in a dictionary and unpack them when calling your function:

```
params = {'param1': 1, 'param2': 4, 'param3': 7}
my_object.DoSomething(**{k: my_function(v) for k, v in params.items()})
```

Comment: Much better than manual typing. Thank you for your input.  Any other ideas are most welcome.